# Drush with several Virtual Hosts on Apache web server

Tags: apache, drupal, virtual, drush

I have several Drupal installs on an Apache2 Web server.
Each install is a separate virtual host on the Document Root, like

```
/var/www/html/site-1
/var/www/html/site-2
/var/www/html/site-3
```

...

I want to perform Drush commands just on "site-1", for example install a module.
In order to do that just for "site-1", should i do the following?

1.) cd /var/www/html/site-1/sites/all/modules
2.) drush en module_name -y

Will the above download and enable "module_name" only for "site-1"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the option `--root`to specify the webroot of your drupal installation. You can also specify the website URL using the option `--uri`, if you have a multisite installation. Look at http://docs.drush.org/en/master/usage/#options for an in-depth description.

But the best way to handle you setup is drush aliases (http://docs.drush.org/en/master/usage/#site-aliases). You define an alias `@site1` etc. and this alias references the webroot and site URL (and optionally other parameters as well).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will enable only site-1. If you just remain in /var/www/html/site-1/, that is enough.